Need Help Communicating with Arduino Leonardo Using Custom Bootloader
I have an Arduino Leonardo that has been flashed with a custom bootloader, and it currently has a sketch on it that I cannot replace or modify because doing so would brick the board. The board works and communicates perfectly with a specific software (which I don’t have the source code for), but I want to communicate with it myself and eventually write my own program to interact with the board.
What I Know:

Bootloader works fine, and the Arduino communicates with another executable.
Baud rate for communication is 57600.
I can’t upload new code to the board (due to fear of bricking it), but I want to send and receive commands.
The owner told me that it uses a mouse parser and HID raw reports. While I could have asked the owner how to communicate with it, I was told that if I can figure out how to use it, he will be okay with it and have no problem but will not tell me directly how to do it.

What I Have Tried:

Using PuTTY to connect via the correct COM port and baud rate (57600), but all I see is a blank terminal, and I can't send or receive data.
Tested different terminal programs (Tera Term, CoolTerm), but the result is the same: no response from the Arduino.
Verified serial settings (8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, no flow control) across all terminals.
Looked into capturing USB traffic between the working executable and the board to understand the protocol, but I haven't been successful so far.
I tried different baud rates (9600, 115200) just in case, but 57600 seems to be the right one.

My Goal:
I want to figure out how to connect to the bootloader or current firmware and communicate with the board using serial commands, so I can eventually write my own software to replicate the functionality of the existing executable.
Any advice on how I can proceed from here? Is there a way to reverse-engineer the communication protocol from the executable? Is there a better tool or method to explore the serial communication?
I looked into Wireshark and I see responses from Arduino aka mouse but still not sure how can that help me make own commands.

Re “Looked into capturing USB traffic between the working executable and the board”: this looks like the most sensible approach. You may try using Wireshark for this.
